# .Net Standard 2.0 library with custom output and intermediate files path?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, xamarin.forms

In a .Net Standard 2.0 library project, what's the correct way to specify custom paths for the output and intermediate files directly?

I tried the configuration below which is working fine for previos versions of the .Net Standard library.

Please notice that those paths are relative to the project, I just copied the same path that were working before upgrading to .Net Standard 2.0, besides anything I put from the IDE settings window is converted to relative paths when saved to .csproj file.

[image]

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    <EnableDefaultEmbeddedResourceItems Condition=" '$(EnableDefaultEmbeddedResourceItems)' == '' ">false</EnableDefaultEmbeddedResourceItems>
    <ProjectName Condition=" '$(ProjectName)' == '' ">MyLibrary</ProjectName>
    <SolutionOutputPath Condition=" '$(SolutionOutputPath)' == '' ">..\..\..\..\..\..\tmp\com.company.myapp</SolutionOutputPath>
    <BaseIntermediateOutputPath>..\..\..\..\..\..\tmp\com.company.myapp\MyLibrary\obj\Debug</BaseIntermediateOutputPath>
</PropertyGroup>

<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <CheckForOverflowUnderflow>false</CheckForOverflowUnderflow>
    <OutputPath>$(SolutionOutputPath)\$(ProjectName)\bin\$(Configuration)</OutputPath>
    <BaseOutputPath>$(SolutionOutputPath)\$(ProjectName)\bin\$(Configuration)</BaseOutputPath>
    <IntermediateOutputPath>$(SolutionOutputPath)\$(ProjectName)\obj\$(Configuration)</IntermediateOutputPath>
    <BaseIntermediateOutputPath>$(SolutionOutputPath)\$(ProjectName)\obj\$(Configuration)</BaseIntermediateOutputPath>
</PropertyGroup>

<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugType></DebugType>
    <CheckForOverflowUnderflow>false</CheckForOverflowUnderflow>
    <OutputPath>$(SolutionOutputPath)\$(ProjectName)\bin\$(Configuration)</OutputPath>
    <BaseOutputPath>$(SolutionOutputPath)\$(ProjectName)\bin\$(Configuration)</BaseOutputPath>
    <IntermediateOutputPath>$(SolutionOutputPath)\$(ProjectName)\obj\$(Configuration)</IntermediateOutputPath>
    <BaseIntermediateOutputPath>$(SolutionOutputPath)\$(ProjectName)\obj\$(Configuration)</BaseIntermediateOutputPath>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

.NET Standard uses msbuild under the hood. So you can use the same properties that you used before: OutputPath, and IntermediateOutputPath.